# How can I translate "tableau" in a theater context?

Tags: translation

How can I translate the word "tableau" (same in French and English) in a theater context? It is the sentence in a scene that informs about changes in setting/location.

Comment: Ĉu tiu estas la fakta signifo? Mi kontrolis en kelkaj vortaroj: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tableau), [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tableau) kaj [Petit Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/tableau), sed iliaj teatraĵaj difinoj ne kongruas kun tiu de la demando.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani For the French word, I’m sure. It has a Wikipedia page : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableau_(théâtre). In Italian, it seems to be «quadro». For the English word, I don’t remember where I found the word. But in a more general way, I would like to know the word in esperanto that designate the sentences in a theater word indicating the changes in setting.

Comment: I agree with Eduardo. Usually the term _tableau_ refer to _tableau vivant_, where actors stay put or move only a little to portrait a scene. For instance, actors come to sit around a table like in the painting _The last supper_ by Leonardo da Vinci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dekoracio` [estas laŭ PIV](https://vortaro.net/#dekoracio_kdc) *Pentritaj toloj aŭ paneloj, prezentantaj la lokon, kie okazas teatra sceno*

Indiko pri ŝanĝo estus unuvorte do `dekoraciŝanĝo`, ankaŭ [difinita en PIV](https://vortaro.net/#dekoraci%C5%9Dan%C4%9Do_kd) kiel: *Anstataŭigo de dekoracio per alia, inter du scenoj aŭ aktoj* Oni tamen ne nepre devas kunmeti, `ŝanĝo/anstataŭigo de dekoracio` same bonus.

Kvankam tio sufiĉus por `tableau` ĝenerale, oni povus aldoni `ne interrompa` se tio gravas.